# Using String methods instead of Regex

Tags: c#, string

as i am not very familiar with regex, is it possible (whether its hard to do or not) to extract certain text inbetween symbols? for example:

```
<meta name="description" content="THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT" />
```

Comment: I don't beleive it will be hard, but for any non-trivial implementations, you are looking at a reasonably large amount of code to write and maintain. And it is unlikey that you will be hitting anywhere near the performance of a Regex.

Comment: RegEx is one of those horribly confusing things that ought not be avoided simply because of its complexity. It's is a great deal more efficient than any standard string method (in most cases) and chances are it's a better choice- even if it does boggle the mind. :-!

Answer (score 5):

Since you give an xml example, just use an xml parser:

```
string s = (string) XElement.Parse(xml).Attribute("content");
```

xml is not a simple text format, and `Regex` isn't really a very good fit; using an appropriate tool will protect you from a range of evils... for example, the following **is identical** as xml:

```
<meta
    name="description"
    content=
        'THIS IS THE TEXT I WANT TO EXTRACT'
/>
```

It also means that when the requirement changes, you have a *simple* tweak to make to the code, rather than trying to unpick a regex and put it back together again (which can be tricky if you are access a non-trivial node). Equally, xpath might be an option; so in your data the xpath:

```
/meta/@content
```

is all you need.

If you haven't got .NET 3.5:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string s = doc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("content");
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you *can* identify the start and the end of your desired substring by string methods such as `IndexOf`, then get the desired `Substring`!  In your example, you want to locate (with `IndexOf`) the "contents=" and then the first following `"`, right?  And once you have those indices into the string, `Substring` will work fine.  (Not posting C# code because I'm not entirely sure of what exactly it IS that you want, beyond IndexOf and Substring...!-)

If so, then:

```
int first = str.IndexOf("contents=\"");
int last = str.IndexOf("\"", first + 10);
return str.Substring(first + 10, last - first - 10);
```

should more or less do what you want (apologies in again if there's an off-by-one or so in those hardcoded `10`s -- they're meant to stand for the length of the first substring you're looking for; adjust them a little bit up or down until you get exactly the result you want!-), but this is the general concept.  Locate the start with single-argument `IndexOf`, locate the end with two-args `IndexOf`, slice off the desired piece with `Substring`...!

Comment: thats right, what i'm after is the text inbetween both quotes like inside the content tag like this: content="i need this text"

Comment: thanks for the code Alex, but its nowhere near close, it always extracts the first 15 or so chars of the beginning of the file.. weird???

Comment: What do you see when you add output statements to show the value of first and last?

Answer (score 1):

if the input is :  text1/text2/text3

```
The below regex will give the 2 in the group i.e, TEXT3

^([^/]*/){2}([^/]*)/$


if you need the last text always, then use the below

^.*/([^/]*)/$
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it with out Regex.  Say you want to get the text between < and >...

```
string GetTextBetween(string content)
{
  int start = content.IndexOf("<");
  if(start == -1) return null; // Not found.
  int end = content.IndexOf(">");
  if(end == -1) return null;  // end not found
  return content.SubString(start, end - start);
}
```